# Need a little bit explanation on this Simple PHP code

Tags: php

I have a large Php code and I understand all the code except for this part.

```
Function emptyFields($ar) {
 If(!is_array($ar)) {
     print "The argument must be an array";
      return false;
  }
 foreach($ar as $key => $value) {
   If(empty($value) {
       print ucwords($key) . " must not be empty";
     return false;
   }
 }
     return true;
}

 if(!emptyFields($_POST) {
 exit();
}
```

I know this is a very simple code. And I understand this to some extent. I just need a detailed explanation on:

> if(!emptyFields($_POST)) {
>       exit();
>       }

Thank you for your time. Sorry for mistakes.

Comment: the line you pointed out calls the `emptyFields` function with the POST variables of the current request. If the call returns false then execution of the php script is halted.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!emptyFields($_POST) {
    exit();
}
```

First of all this is actually wrong. It should be

```
if(!emptyFields($_POST)) {
    exit();
}
```

What the function actually does is accepts a parameter. First it checks if that parameter is array and if it is not it will return false.

After that if goes through every element of the array and check if it is empty, if so it again returns false. !Note here, in php `empty()` will return true to an `int 0`;

The last part of the code send to the function the global array $_POST and if it returns false it stops executing. I guess this is some sort of a check to see if the user send some empty fields to the server.

EDIT:

The `!` operator is the same as `== false`. So if the `emptyFields` function returns false, the `exit()` function will be executed.

Comment: I understand what this code does. What does the yellow portion mean? I mean, if not emptyFields exit(); does this mean that if function doeesn't execute, exit?

Comment: i also explained that.

Comment: So '!' Operator relates to "return true". If !true exit(). Am i right?

Comment: @user5237857 It doesn't mean if the function doesn't execute. If you say if( someFunction() ) { //something }, then you are saying, when someFunction() is run, if the value that is returned by that function evaluates as true (can be a positive number, boolean true, or non-empty string) then the //something portion will be run. The exclamation point is the reverse of that, so it will only run if the function returns a false value (0, boolean false, or empty string).

So in your case, if the function emptyFields($_POST) returns false,  (one of the first two return statements), exit() will run.

Comment: @imkingdavid actually there's a confusion. As you said, If it returned any of first two return statements, exit() will run. ! For third return statement actually means, if !true, exit(). But for any of the first two return statements, it means, if !false i.e if not false, run exit(). I think ! Only works for "return true". What do you say?

Comment: @user5237857 An if() statement will excute the code within the curly brackets if and only if all of the statements in the parentheses evaluate to true. emptyFields() can only return true or false. Your code may then exit() depending on the return value. If it returns false, the if statement will be: `if(!false)`. Because `!false === true`, that is the same as saying `if(true)`, so the exit() will run. If emptyFields() returns true, the if statement will be: `if(!true)`. Because `!true === false`, that is the same as saying `if(false)`, so the exit() will not be reached.

Comment: @imkingdavi and vasil shadix bros could you please up vote my question. Somebody down voted it. Idk why? Have I asked something that isn't allowed? It's a HELP ME WITH MY CODE website.